# Why loading webview sometimes works and sometimes finishes fast?

Tags: android, webview, android-websettings

I have an android app using `webview`. I show my entire website. My problem is when I click on buttons on a navigation to load a page sometimes they open by first touch and sometimes nothing works. I have to touch the button 2 , 3 or more times and they will open.

This also exists for urls in the website. It is really weird behavior and I don't know the reason.

By using `pageStart()` and page finish I see it starts but when progress percent is 10 `pageFinish()` says it has stopped loading!

The problem doesn't exists in android studio simulator just in real mobiles. (and exists in different mobiles and android versions)

Here is part of my code if needed.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}


public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.searchAds) {
    startWebView("http://www.test.com/");
} else if (id == R.id.myPage) {
    startWebView("http://www.test.com/profile");
} else if (id == R.id.allNewPosts) {
    startWebView("http://www.test.com/");
} else if (id == R.id.followingsNewPosts) {
    startWebView("http://www.test.com/new/");
} else if (id == R.id.followingsNewPosts) {
    startWebView("http://www.test.com/categories/");
}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}

private void startWebView(String myURL) {

if (!isNetworkStatusAvialable(getApplicationContext())) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet access" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl(myURL);
}
}


public class Client extends WebViewClient {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
}

//If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (!url.contains("test.com")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}


//Show loader on url load
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    // Then show progress  Dialog
    if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("test.com")) {
        // in standard case YourActivity.this
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading ...");
        progressDialog.show();


    }
}

 // Called when all page resources loaded
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
        // Close progressDialog
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
            progressRunning = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: it happens because of network internet speed or connection, Phone Speed, when ever your speed slow then it load in more time if speed is fast then web view data load quick.also some times view reflect which you can not see Perfect in webview .because of speed....

Comment: @amitasharma it happens too much times ! i mean i dont think its because of internet speed because its good enough. even pages with just "hi" message cant load ! it loads all of those pages just to 10 % and finishes! if it was because of internet speed progress must change slower :(

Comment: in your phone have you checked in background some other Apps are running or not at same time if there are some other is running then speed can slow ... In Code your are Loading your URL to webview may be there is a big data on that url so it taking time to Display....

Comment: Can you confirm that your internet connection is stable without request time out?

Comment: @amitasharma yes other apps use internet too ! like whats app , telegram..  but my problem is all page loadings stop at 10 % ! not different when you tough or which page or link you touch ! and when reaches 10 % onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) functions shows it !

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono sorry i dont know what i can do for it ? (how to check ?) :p     but i am sure it is not because of internet speed because its transfer rate is 250 kB/s  and in such situations it doesnt download 1 KB !   i think maybe some kind of error happens that i dont know :(

Comment: @Saeid You can try ping to your web server and check if the connection is stable without dropped package/request time out. I am afraid if your connection is not stable, it will lead to the behaviour like you said.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am totally late to the party, but I had the same issue and I managed to find a workaround for anyone having trouble. My experience was that around 7-8 out of 10 times, the webView would load correctly, but sometimes it wouldn't with no particular reason, at least to my understanding.

I still don't know the cause of this, but **since this behavior concerns only the 10% progress** (after countless runs, I never had it stuck before or after 10%) and most calls are successful, when the progress is 10% I start a postDelayed Runnable that will run after some time. If after this time lapse the progress is still at 10%, I just reload the URL. Since most calls are successful, the user may experience only a few seconds delay even at consecutive fails, but will have the url loaded for sure. Personally It has never failed me.

**Note :** The `onLoadResource` is implemented inside a class that `extends WebViewClient`

**Warning :** I used this logic to load some docs and static pages. If you want your webview to go forward, backwards etc. I'd suggest also implementing the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` or `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` depending on your API and change the url in `view.loadUrl(yourURL)` accordingly!

I hope it helps somebody!

```
private int _progress = 0;
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(final WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        _progress = view.getProgress();
        if (_progress == 10){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, ""+view.getProgress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(_progress == 10){
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "RELOADING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        view.loadUrl(yourURL);
                    }
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
        if(view.getProgress() == 100) {
        //URL LOADED
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat similar problem I post delayed the url loading after webView Rendering.

```
webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                fetchData();
            }
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Probably that's a good solution, but it waits 0.5 second. Is there any event to understand that a page is loading? I mean, start to load, understand that it is not loaded and postpone for 500 ms.

Comment: Yes as you see in the above question there are two methods `WebViewClient `   i.e. `onLoadResource`  and `onPageFinished ` that will help you identify the resources are being loaded and finished.

Comment: Yes, also `onPageStarted` to start. I didn't face the situation, so ask, what to do if start instantly and reload if page was not finished in 500 ms.

Comment: I may not be getting you right.. but the above mentioned solution doesn't state the page will finish reloading in 500ms. its actually starting loading process of the url in Webview after its rendering is complete. So you can say that Start fetching page ... 500ms after the Webivew is rendered.. because i was facing the issue that my Webview was rendered in parallel thread to fetching the url, so i delayed to 500ms to make sure the url is loaded after Webview rendering.